# No consigo asociar dos tablas en MySQL - Sequelize (usuario y proveedor)

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, sequelize.js, sequelize

llevo varios días intentando asociar dos tablas / modelos en MySQL - Sequelize (un 1:1 de toda la vida) y no sé cómo es la manera correcta de asociarlos.

Mi código es el siguiente:

- Tabla usuarios

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const User = sequelize.define("user", {
    idUser: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      unique: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    nameUser: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      validate: { notEmpty: true },
    },
    emailUser: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: true,
      validate: { isEmail: true },
    },
    activeUser: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    },
  });

  User.associate = (models) => {
    User.hasOne(Provider);
  };
```

- Tabla proveedores

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const Provider = sequelize.define("provider", {
    idProvider: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    nameProvider: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    idUser: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      //unique: true,
    },
    isPublicProvider: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    },
  });

  Provider.associate = (models) => {
    Provider.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: "idUser", as: "idUser" });
  };
```

Y no me da errores al ejecutar la aplicación, pero sí que cuando voy a MySQL workbench, veo que no está asociado de ninguna manera (err diagram)

Adjunto una imagen para que podáis verlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano!